# Tcpdf image not showing while using in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF and getting content from a MySQL table row which is holding HTML like:

```
<p>Internet users are our primary target market. We do not charge the consumer any fee
for using our services or to make purchases online. We do not add any fee or commission on products that you compare and purchase online</p>
<p><img src="http://1/2/3/x.jpg" width="x" height="x"></p>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. What's the question? How does this HTML relate to TCPDF and Codeigniter?

Comment: show your code whitch adds image

Answer (score 0):

In Tcpdf make sure your path is relative path not http path
EX

> `realpath(APPPATH."../1/2/3/x.jpg")`

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF does not support absolute path. you have to use relative path.

use `realpath` function in `PHP`

Other things to look at, read access to the images from the script. you have to set the permission chmod to 777 or 755 to image containing folder.

Comment: If my answer is working for you then mark it as correct to help other people facing same issue. glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

please try with div >image or table >> tr > td > image some other tag instead of p > image 
(which contains the image tag  )

Answer (score 0):

By giving relative path to the image instead of giving the absolute path have a look below code .It should be useful i think.

```
<img src="<?php echo 'layouts/images/'.$decscript ?>"/>
```